# How do I login as root

Tags: root

In order to change the usb device mount from 'media' to 'scd' I need root privleges. How do I sign in as root using XTERM?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is:

Open the `terminal`(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), and enter the following command:

```
sudo xterm
```

This will prompt you to enter the root user password. Enter it, and xterm will open as root.

Hope this helped.